# SP-Import 'File Not Found' error

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, import

I am trying to import an Enterprise wiki site I have created from its test location to its live location which will be a new site collection.

`SP-Export` worked fine and the `SP-Import` also completed with no errors. But when I try to access any of the site pages, documents etc I get the error:

Error

> File Not Found.

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow these steps:**

1. Navigate to `C:\inetpub\wwroot\wss\Virtual Directories\your web app's virtual directory` here.

   - You can also open IIS
   - Expand Sites
   - Right click on your **SharePoint** site
   - Choose explore
   - proceed to step 2
2. Copy and paste the **web.config** file (making a backup)
3. Open web.config using notepad
4. Search for “**CallStack**” , set this equal to true
5. Search for “**Custom**”, set the `customerrors = “Off”`
6. Search for “**Debug**”, set Debug = “True”

   7. Save the **web.config** file and refresh your page in the browser

**You should now see what the error actually is.**

Many times it is a web part assembly reference missing from the web.config , custom master page missing or something similar.

This should at least give you a more precise troubleshooting starting point. Remember to turn **CustomErrors** back “**On**” in the web.config after fixing the issue so that your end users won’t see an ugly Asp.Net error if this happens again.

Comment: As this is the live environment will this stop my other sites from working while in debug mode?

Comment: No it will not affect any of the sites but when you find the appropriate error than you should revert all the steps.

Comment: Make sure to first take backup of the **web.config** file. If something goes wrong than you can use the backup.

Comment: The error looks quite generic? Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.  Source Error: Line 376:    <customErrors mode="off" />

Comment: No it is the misconfiguration of the steps mentioned in my answer. Please revert all the changes

Comment: I fixed the misconfig, new error: Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41861/discussion-between-hardik-and-user3560464).

Comment: Thankyou, it was the master page which needed to be changed

Comment: Glad to help you...:)